Reduce 4th order differential equation to 2nd order
I have the fourth-order differential equation:
$$
\partial_x^2\log\bigg(\frac{h''(x)}{\sinh(h(x))}\bigg)-\coth(h(x))\,h''(x)=0.
$$
It has the solution (in case that might help somebody with my question):
$$
h(x)=2\,p\,x+\log\bigg(\frac{(e^{2\,x}-1)(1+2\,p)\gamma^2}{e^{2\,x(1+2\,p)}-\gamma^4}\bigg),
$$
for $p$ an integer and $\gamma$ real.
Is it possible to reduce that fourth-order differential equation to second order?
It comes from some system of gravity coupled to matter in 3 dimensions. The reason I suspect that it might be reducible to second-order comes from a similar looking equation (which is second order in itself) in another gravity system with matter in 5 dimensions that describes similar physics. From that system I feel that the reduction to second order might look like:
$$
f_1(z)\,\partial_z\bigg(\frac{g'(z)}{\sinh(g(z))}\bigg)+f_2(z)\coth(g(z))=0.
$$
for functions $f_{1,2}(z)$ to be determined. The second-order equation in 5 dimensions that made me think the fourth-order one might be reducible has $f_1(z)=\sinh(g(z))$ and $f_2(z)=c_2\,z$ for $c_2$ a constant.
The reason I have used $z$ instead of $x$ is that one might need to change dependent variables. I personally tried with $x=-\log(y)$ and looked for some substitution of $h(y)$ there, but I couldn't think of anything. I am really bad at this type of manipulations, so I am hopeful somebody can help me.
